# How to point a naked domain at Heroku app without setting a custom domain

Tags: heroku, dns

I've got a domain `wildcard.xyz` and an app hosted on Heroku. When I try to add `wildcard.xyz` as a custom domain on Heroku, it won't let me ("wildcard" is reserved  ).

I can add `www.wildcard.xyz`, point a CNAME `www` to `www.wildcard.xyz.herokudns.com` and the www works fine, but can't seem to find any way to point the apex to Heroku. I'm using DNSimple.

None of these have worked so far:

- ALIAS to www.wildcard.xyz.herokudns.com (Heroku says "no app found")
- ALIAS to myapp123.herokuapp.com (doesn't work for HTTPS)
- CNAME * to wildcard.wildcard.xyz.herokudns.com (doesn't catch apex)
- URL apex to www (URL record redirect doesn't work for HTTPS)

Any ideas of how I can get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. Have you tried using DNSimple's one-click Heroku setup? https://dnsimple.com/services

Comment: The two options for Heroku at DNSimple are: ALIAS example.com > myapp.herokuapp.com + CNAME www.example.com > myapp.herokuapp.com (which doesn't work for HTTPS) and ALIAS example.com > example.com.herokudns.com + CNAME www.example.com > www.example.com.herokudns.com (which doesn't work because herokudns.com doesn't accept domains starting with "wildcard"). Were you able to resolve your issue?